# TypeError:Undefined not an object evaluating('_useContext.add_location')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new on react native and i am getting an error in my app. I am trying to make a map to get the user location and track the location using context and provider and getting an error while rendering the map. **TypeError:Undefined not an object evaluating('_useContext.add_location')**
Here is my 
LocationContext.js
file.

```
import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";


const LocationContext = (state, action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'add_current_location':
            return {...state, currentLocation: action.payload};
        default:
            return state;

    }
};
const add_Location = dispatch => (location) =>{
    dispatch({type:'add_current_location', payload: location})
};

const startRecording = dispatch => () => {
};

const stopRecording= dispatch =>()=>{
};


export const {Context, Provider}= createDataContext( LocationContext,
    {startRecording, stopRecording, add_Location },
    {recording: false, location:[],currentLocation:null}
);
```

Here is my TrackCreateScreen.js

```
//import '../_mockLocation';
import React, {useEffect, useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Text} from "react-native-elements";
import {SafeAreaView} from "react-native";
import Map from "../components/Map";
import {requestPermissionsAsync, watchPositionAsync, Accuracy} from "expo-location";
import { Context as LocationContext } from "../context/LocationContext";



const TrackCreateScreen = () => {
    const { add_Location } = useContext(LocationContext);
    const [err, setErr] = useState(null);


    const startWatching = async () => {
        try {
            await requestPermissionsAsync();
            await watchPositionAsync({
                accuracy: Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
                timeInterval: 1000,
                distanceInterval: 10
            }, location => { add_Location(location)
            });
        } catch (e) {
            setErr(e);

        }
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        startWatching();
    }, []);


    return (
        <SafeAreaView forceInset={{top: 'always'}}>
            <Text h3>TrackCreate Screen</Text>
            <Map/>
            {err ? <Text>Please enable services</Text> : null}
        </SafeAreaView>

    );

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    textStyle:
        {
            fontSize: 48
        }


});

export default TrackCreateScreen;
```

Here is my dependencies.

```
"expo": "~36.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~8.0.0",
    "ngrok": "^3.2.7",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3"
```

[Here is the error shown on the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXswz.png)